# NAA Flag declined when answer was recommended for deletion

Tags: discussion

I flagged the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637996/powermail-prefill-some-fields-with-content-only-one-query/41672443#41672443 (which has since been removed) as NAA after it looked like the following:

> On a registration form I use the prefill feature as suggested, too.

The answerer does the same thing as the OP, which is not really relevant

> I looked also for a better implementation, but didn`t get it working.

I tried another method but it did not work.

> Fetching all relevent data in just one query would be way better.

Doing what you suggest at the bottom of your question sounds good.

> Maybe using registers could to the job.

Small attempt to offer some insight.

The only really relevant part of the answer was the last statement but that does not (in my opinion and in the opinion of the person who commented on said answer) quantify an answer.  This flag was declined for the reason:

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Yet from it's reviews it seems that the majority of people thought the same: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14897833, did I make the right call in flagging this answer as NAA?

EDIT:

It's not so much that the answer provided gives no heading what-so-ever, the concern was more over the brevity of the answer, registers is a very general term and had I been provided with what was essentially "Try registers." as an answer I would not have know where to proceed from there.

Comment: *"but that does not quantify an answer"* Someone thought it did. Moderators have an extremely low bar for what constitutes "an answer". This one will get reviewed by the community instead, which will almost certainly produce the desired outcome.

Comment: On the gripping hand: the entire Q&A has been deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you cut away the chatter, you are left with the last line:

> Maybe using registers could to the job.

That right there is an attempt to provide an answer, and is why I declined the NAA flag. We are not left with *Dude, did you solve this yet?* or *We need more information to answer this* or *I tried to do foo once, how did you make the bar fly?* or *Follow this tutorial here*.

I don't know why reviewers in the queue flagged it as NAA. Perhaps they had not read the whole post. Perhaps they only saw the first sentence, where the answerer proclaimed to have met the same problem, but that's not the sole content of the post! Or perhaps they read that last sentence in a different light.

As answers go, it is pretty bad, so feel free to downvote it. I certainly admit it is a borderline call, and if I hadn't seen it in our queue, the community could have chosen to delete it with NAA flags alone, and that would probably have been fine too. (And the community has certainly voted to delete it since).

Comment: ... or maybe they applied a harsher standard of what constitutes an answer than you, and decided that one brief sentence of speculation that some broad feature could maybe be used in an unspecified way to solve the problem doesn't count as an answer. Or maybe they didn't care much about whether the post was technically "not an answer", and just decided that it was crap enough that the site would be better if it were deleted. I'm not voicing a view either way on whether it would be *good* for them to apply such reasoning, but both seem like quite likely possibilities.

Comment: @MarkAmery they handle hundred's each day, I'm also not happy that this NAA flag get denied http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336562/visual-studio-error-d8016-zi-and-o2-command-line-options-are-incompatible/41576934#41576934,  I even tried to comment to help out, but in the end the flow of NAA is just to huge even for mods to evaluate precisely each NAA flag, I'm ok with a 0.1% error rate.

Comment: IMHO, the sentence sounds more like a shot in the dark than an answer to me

Comment: @ochi: NAA flags are only meant to be used on posts that are *not attempting to answer*. A shot in the dark is still an attempt to answer. It doesn't matter how badly the attempt fails.